Virtual key not working in Gnome terminal with XLib
I have an application written in C that prints any key. If I have an active window with an editor such as Notepad, the key works, if I have an active window with Gnome Terminal, nothing is written. Could someone advise how to solve this. I am using Ubuntu 23.10 environment.
The main goal of my project is that I have a serial keyboard that sends ASCII characters and I need to convert them to classic keys. The result should be a full-fledged keyboard.
example I tried.
`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main() {
    while(1) {
        Display *display;
        unsigned int keycode;

        display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_C);
        XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
        XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, 0);
        XFlush(display);
        sleep(5);
    
    }

    return 0; 
}

`

This may be a result of Xsecurity blocking fake events to the terminal emulator application.

This prevents using a keylogger to capture passwords or spoofing input to a terminal while it's logged in as root, which is a security problem.

And how could it be bypassed?

In MacOS Terminal there's a "Secure Keyboard Entry" menu setting. I don't use Linux, but before posting my comment I googled for something equivalent in Gnome Terminal, but couldn't find it. You might have better luck asking on [unix.se].

Thank you very much, I finally solved it by writing to "/dev/uinput". I also tried "/dev/input/event" but it needs a classic keyboard connected.

You should put the solution in an answer.
